# How to make a third party plugin for Qt using another DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-c++, dll

Disclaimer: everything works fine on Linux. On Windows, I have recently changed from MinGW to MSVC2012 because I couldn't read MP3 properly (see [Make the WMF plugin compile with MinGW.](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Multimedia))

In my project, I have :

- Core (DLL)
- Another DLL built using Core
- A Media Player (the Qt App, using both DLL and loading plugins)

To keep my project cross-platform, I also extracted Windows specific features ([progress bar, thumbnail buttons](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwinextras-index.html)) into a 3rd party plugin. In fact, I'm starting to write a plugin manager, which loads/unloads plugin at runtime and without restarting the app, it's working fine.

But since I've switched to MSVC, I cannot build my plugins anymore. I'm facing:

> *C4273: 'staticMetaObject' : inconsistent dll linkage*

I don't know how to proceed... I have the following structure:

#### In MainProject\Core\Interfaces

```
 class MIAMCORE_LIBRARY MediaPlayerPluginInterface : public BasicPluginInterface
 {
 public:
     virtual ~MediaPlayerPluginInterface() {}

     virtual void setMediaPlayer(QWeakPointer<MediaPlayer>) = 0;

     virtual bool providesView() const = 0;

     virtual void toggleViews(QWidget *) {}
 };
```

#### In Plugin.h

```
class Minimode : public QWidget, public MediaPlayerPluginInterface
{
            Q_OBJECT
            Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID MediaPlayerPluginInterface_iid)
            Q_INTERFACES(MediaPlayerPluginInterface)

    private:
            Ui::ConfigForm _ui;

            QWeakPointer<MediaPlayer> _mediaPlayer;
            bool _startMoving;
            QPoint _pos, _globalPos;

    public:
            explicit Minimode();

            virtual ~Minimode();
            inline virtual QString name() const { return "Minimode"; }
            inline virtual QString version() const { return "1.0"; }
            inline virtual bool providesView() const { return true; }
            virtual QWidget* configPage();
            virtual void setMediaPlayer(QWeakPointer<MediaPlayer> mediaPlayer);
            virtual void toggleViews(QWidget *view);
    protected:
            /** Redefined to be able to drag this widget on screen. */
            void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e);

            /** Redefined to be able to drag this widget on screen. */
            void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e);

            void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e);

    private:
            void applyColorToStandardIcon(QPushButton *button);

    };
```

#### My Plugin.pro

```
QT      += widgets multimedia
TARGET   = $$qtLibraryTarget(mini-mode)
TEMPLATE = lib

MiamPlayerBuildDirectory = C:\dev\Miam-Player\build\MiamPlayer
DEFINES += MINIMODE_MIAMPLUGIN

CONFIG  += c++11
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    target.path = $$MiamPlayerBuildDirectory\debug\plugins
    LIBS += -Ldebug -lMiamCore
}

INSTALLS += target
```

#### Miamcore_global.h

```
#ifndef MIAMCORE_GLOBAL_H
#define MIAMCORE_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/QtGlobal>

#if defined(MIAMCORE_LIBRARY)
#undef MIAMCORE_LIBRARY
#define MIAMCORE_LIBRARY Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#define MIAMCORE_LIBRARY Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // MIAMCORE_GLOBAL_H
```

I have tried various permutations with the macro MIAMCORE_LIBRARY, and with another MINIMODE_PLUGIN but none of them worked (between class and Minimode but not shown above). Should I add specific keywords in my *.pro files ?

Comment: Show the definition of "MIAMCORE_LIBRARY", and fix your code formatting in the meantime...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your macro seems to be wrong for the export and import.

Provided, you do not need static building for the plugins which is a somewhat real expectation since those are meant to be dynamic libraries, you should use your macro like below.

Please also note that, you forgot to include the global Qt header where the import and export macro are defined.

#### Miamcore_global.h

```
#ifndef MIAMCORE_GLOBAL_H
#define MIAMCORE_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#ifdef MINIMODE_MIAMPLUGIN
# define MIAMCORE_LIBRARY Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
# define MIAMCORE_LIBRARY Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // MIAMCORE_GLOBAL_H
```

Then you will need to specify the following define in your project file:

#### YourPlugin.pro

```
...
DEFINES += MINIMODE_MIAMPLUGIN
...
```

This design works fine in our plugin architecture with Qt 4 as well as Qt 5 on Windows and Unix.

The import thing is Windows here. It would be just fine on Linux without this, but for Windows, you need to make sure to export the plugins when building it, but import when you are actually using it.

That is why you need to pass the desired designation to the project file that this build time, export it. Once, your users will use the plugin, this define will not be there anymore, and then it will be imported.